# Variables in Python functions on RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, led

sudo python yantest.py 255,255,0

```
who = sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[1]
print who
print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
yanon(strip, Color(who))
```

output from above is

```
255,255,0

255,255,0

Number of arguments: 2 arguments.

Argument List: ['yantest.py', '255,255,0']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yantest.py", line 46, in <module>
    yanon(strip, Color(who))
TypeError: Color() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
Segmentation fault
```

How do I use the variable "who" inside the Color function?

Ive tried ('who'), ("who") neither of which work either.

Comment: We don't know what `Color` is, but according to the error, it is expecting 3 argent's but you only pass it one: `who`

Comment: who = 255,255,0 which si the 3 arguments it needs.  Color(who) doesnt seem to convert to the contents of the variable.

Comment: No, actually `who == "255,255,0"` but that doesn't really address my comment

Comment: Yes, it does. The *value of `who`* is a string, `"255,255,0"`. You pass that as a single argument. But, it looks like `Color` takes three `int` arguments

Comment: you are correct.  I split the string by , and then converted to int.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Color() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Error means that you should pass 3 arguments but you only pass 1 argument. Here are two ways to implement:

```
color_r = sys.argv[1]
color_g = sys.argv[2]
color_b = sys.argv[3]
yanon(strip, Color(color_r, color_g, color_b))
```

Run script as:

```
sudo python yantest.py 255 255 0
```

OR

```
who = sys.argv[1].split(',')
yanon(strip, Color(who[0], who[1], who[2]))
```

Run script as:

```
sudo python yantest.py 255,255,0
```

And you should care about the type of argument!

Comment: this works perfectly.  thanks.  I did have to convert to int as well.  so the line is yanon(strip, Color(int(who[0]), int(who[1]), int(who[2])))

not sure why downvoted.  works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

who is a string. I don't know what type of variable color should get but probably int. You should split who string to 3 sub strings by "," and convert each one to int or whatever it should be.